# How can I inject a declared namespace with Angular DI?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I'm trying to inject the npm url node_module into my service in Angular.

I know I can simply just do:

```
import * as url from 'url';
```

and can use it in my class as follows:

```
url.format(); //using it
```

Although I want to inject it, since I believe I should catch errors sooner, by forcing all my classes to initialize with their dependencies in the constructor.

I know I can use injector Tokens with an interface and useValue to inject simple values.

```
interface MyInterface {
  property: string
}
const JS_PRETEND_TYPING = new InjectionToken<MyInterface>('small_desc');
const MY_VALUE = { a: 123 }

@NgModule({
  providers: [ { provide: JS_PRETEND_TYPING, useValue: MY_VALUE } ]
});
```

Although the url package has it's typing's declared as a module.

In url package:

```
declare module "url" {
    export interface UrlObject { 
    ...
}
```

So I can't do this because I get an error:

```
import * as url from 'url';


// ERROR: Cannot use namespace 'url' as a type. const
JS_PRETEND_TYPING_FOR_URL = new InjectionToken<url>('small_desc');
```

How can I inject the 'url' npm package into my service in Angular?

```
import * as url from 'url';
class MyService {
   constructor(@Inject(JS_PRETEND_TYPING_FOR_URL) private url: url)
}
```

Comment: What if you use `InjectionToken<any>`?

Comment: @J.Pichardo - I could do that, but I also want to be able to use the typing that is provided with the node module.

Comment: While you keep the type declaration in the constructor there should be no issue.

Comment: @J.Pichardo Thanks for the comment I got it to be injected with the typing provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `url` is not a type. Classes have types of same names associated with them, but variables, functions and namespaces don't.

It should be:

```
constructor(@Inject(JS_PRETEND_TYPING_FOR_URL) private url: typeof url)
```

It is generally overkill to use DI for library imports, unless it's known that it will benefit them somehow (testing, etc). In case of `url` this doesn't make sense. It could be tested by spying on its methods. It's very unlikely that there will be a need to swap it with something else by means of DI.

Comment: But how can I create a constant for JS_PRETEND_TYPING_FOR_URL? Did you use InjectorToken to create JS_PRETEND_TYPING_FOR_URL?

Comment: Yes, provider token should be either a class or injection token, likely `const JS_PRETEND_TYPING = new InjectionToken<typeof url>('url')`