# Derive type from JS object

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript2.0, tsc

I have this object:

```
export interface ClientOpts {
  key: string,
  listener: Function,
  host: string,
  port: number
  unlockRequestTimeout: number;
  lockRequestTimeout: number;
  unlockRetryMax: number;
  lockRetryMax: number;
  ttl: number
}
```

I am wondering if there is a way to derive the above from an object like so:

```
export const validConstructorOptions = {
  key: 'string',
  listener: 'Function',
  host: 'string',
  port: 'number',
  unlockRequestTimeout: 'number',
  lockRequestTimeout: 'number',
  unlockRetryMax: 'number',
  lockRetryMax: 'number'
};
```

one way to do this, would be something like this instead:

```
   export const validConstructorOptions = {
      key: 'string',
      listener: ()=>{},
      host: 'string',
      port: 999,
      unlockRequestTimeout: 999,
      lockRequestTimeout: 999,
      unlockRetryMax: 999,
      lockRetryMax: 999
    };
```

and then do

```
export type ClientOpts = typeof validConstructorOptions;
```

but I am wondering if there is some way to do this using just the strings in the object.

Comment: Related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403800/how-can-i-inject-a-declared-namespace-with-angular-di#comment87823287_50403800?

Answer (score 1):

> but I am wondering if there is some way to do this using just the strings in the object.

No, there isn't.

There is [an open discussion](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3628) on a related subject: how to obtain metadata that could be used at runtime, from a TypeScript type. But so far the TS team doesn't want to implement anything for that.